# How can config to recompile in phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm using phoenix to create a server and using editor VSCode.

When I start server: `mix phx.server` and I have code change, it doesn't recompile, I must turn off and run again.

Should have extension or config set somewhere that can recompile automatically?

file **dev.exs**

```
config :jwtuser, Jwtuser.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 5000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]
```

in **mix.exs**

```
def project do
    [
      app: :jwtuser,
      version: "0.0.1",
      elixir: "~> 1.4",
      elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
      compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      aliases: aliases(),
      deps: deps(),
      erlc_options: erlc_options()
    ]
  end
```

Comment: @matov thanks for edited.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to see your changes while developing, you can start your server in an IEx session with:

```
iex -S mix phx.server
```

And then use

```
IEx.Helpers.recompile
```

To recompile your code.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don’t need any extension, `brunch` does this out of the box. Make sure you did not use `--no-brunch` option while generating the project scaffold, make sure you have assets compiled as shown [here](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/up_and_running.html#content) and make sure you have `watch` option enabled in your `assets/package.json` :

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "deploy": "brunch build --production",
    "watch": "brunch watch --stdin"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "6.1.1",
    "brunch": "2.10.9",
    "clean-css-brunch": "2.10.0",
    "uglify-js-brunch": "2.10.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, I found the answer.